# C++ To use correctly cout wcout ifstream to read text file with accented characters

Tags: c++, ubuntu, locale, ifstream

I want to read a file txt encoded UTF8 on Ubuntu 20.04.

I added a locale fr_FR.UTF-8 to wcout cout and ifstream.

I was thinking just to add locale was enough.

output gives this :

[image]

Here my code

```
...
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
    
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    
    int nbreLigne;
    std::vector<std::wstring> dico;
    std::string path("liste_test.txt");
    std::wstring ligne;
    
    std::locale loc("fr_FR.UTF-8");
    std::cout.imbue(loc);
    std::wcout.imbue(loc);
    std::wifstream file(path.c_str(), std::ios::in);
    file.imbue(loc);
    std::cout << "Path = " << path << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1- locale wifstream : " << file.getloc().name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2- locale wcout : " << std::wcout.getloc().name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "3- locale cout : " <<  std::cout.getloc().name() << std::endl;
    /* Pas d'erreur de compile mais ne semble pas avoir d'effet 
    file.imbue(std::locale(file.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::consume_header>));
    std::cout << "1- Variable de localisation : " << file.getloc().name();
    */

    if (file){
        
        //compte les lignes      
        while (std::getline(file, ligne)){
            nbreLigne++;
            dico.push_back(ligne);

            /*
            Erreur de segmentation (core dumped) si cette ligne est activée
            std::wcout << dico[nbreLigne] << std::endl; 
            */
        }
    
        std::cout << "Total lines number = " << nbreLigne << std::endl;
        
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "ERREUR: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier." << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "-------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Lecture de la variable dico" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < nbreLigne; i++){
       std::wcout << dico[i] << std::endl;
    }
    
...
```

How to use correctly locale with cout, wcout and ifstream ?

Comment: On an unrelated note: You don't need the `nbreLigne` variable. The number of lines read will be the `size()` of  the vector, i.e. `dico.size()`.

Comment: @Some programmer dude  Ok thanks for your advice. It' more efficiency

Comment: Imbueing UTF-8 into `std::wcout` specifies, basically, that your terminal must be a UTF-8 terminal. It is not. Imbuing a character set into `std::cout`, or any other character stream, doesn't seem to do anything useful. Finally, mixed usage of `cout` and `wcout` needs to be done ***very carefully***, with explicit flushes.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik
I am on Ubuntu . My terminal is on UTF8 Unicode

Comment: If you are reading UTF-8 content, and your terminal is UTF-8, then what exactly do you expect that imbuing a UTF-8 locale accomplishes? It will not do anything, whatsoever.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Because if i don't add locale to wifstream the while loop doesn't do anything

Answer (score 1):

To simply answer, **there's no universal way to handle accented character in C++** and most programming languages. Only ASCII is *almost* universal and only cover english characters. With time, multiple solutions to handle language specific characters has born from [Windows code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page) to [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) trough [wide-char](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character) (`std::wcout` is for those wide-chars).

Your problem is not your program (unless that it should only use `std::cout` in this case) but your dictionary that use a different character-set than the one of your terminal.

Solving character-set problems is hard and boring. In your case, rewriting the dictionary by hand in UTF-8 or using [`iconv(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv) is worth. In real projects, you will use an *internationalization* (i18n) tool like [GNU gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) that will handle this burden for you. Today, most modern systems use UTF-8.

Also, setting the locale on a C++ stream only change how the program format values like the decimal separator when you `<<` a float, it cannot change the console locale because `std::cin` is not necessarily a terminal and can be very weird.